# Workflow can't update promoted field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a form made in Infopath in the form there is a field called "FileName" it has a default value "Now()" and has been promoted and the tick to allow edit has been set.

I want to update this field for existing forms by running a workflow.

But when I try to update the field from a SPD workflow nothing happens, the workflow complete's with no error, but the field is not updated.

If i create a new form and try to run the workflow then the "Now()" is overwritten correct.

Comment: Are you storing the whole form in a form library or do you use the form with a list and are unable to update existing **entries**?

Comment: I'm storing the form in a form library

Comment: Sorry, never worked with that. :/